# How can I answer questions with affiliate links?

Tags: discussion, answers, hyperlinks, spam, affiliate

I am new here. As an affiliate marketer, what can I do to be able to post affiliate links to answers questions about new technology, health and design on stackoverflow.com?

Comment: [How to not be a spammer](/help/promotion)

Comment: To put it simply.  **You don't** Can't you answer questions without providing affiliation links? I would almost certainly report any affliction link that wasn't Stack Exchanges own affliction link as spam.

Comment: I do want to say *thank you* for asking first before spamming the site with affiliate links and getting yourself banned!

Answer (score 12):

In short:  Don't.  Not how you describe.

Answering a question with a good and detailed post, with a link to your website (remember to disclose your affiliation) to support what you've posted is okay **once in a while.**  If you go on a "spamming spree", however, and post 5 low-quality (e.g. link-only) answers with links to your website in an hour, your posts will be flagged as spam and deleted.  Stack Exchange is not the place to blatantly promote your website with disregard for the rules concerning affiliate links.  To support what I've written, here's a link to [how not to be a spammer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/promotion), from the Stack Exchange Help Center and with no affiliation whatsoever.

Comment: If every answer you submit has a link to your own website, that’s spam, when Ollie says “once in awhile” they truly mean it to be the exception. We want content here, not on your website, and hopefully original content